# Printing the positions MATRIX of the values in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, position

I have a matrix with some values. I want to get the m,n positions of each value into a separate matrix.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((3,3)) #Creating "a" matrix with all zeros
vals = [22,34,43,56,37,45] # the values that i want to add to the matrix "a"
pos = [(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1)] # Corresponding positions of the above given values

rows, cols = zip(*pos)   # This code is to assign the given values in the correct position

a[rows, cols] = vals

print (a)
```

output =

```
[[(0,0) (0,1) (0,2)]

[(1,0) (1,1) (1,2)]

[(2,0) (2,1) (2,2)]]
```

please help me out.

I want to get the position matrix(m,n) of whatever a matrix (m,n)

Comment: I don't get the relation between what you said and what is in your piece of code. Could you edit the post to add references to the variables in the code? Because currently I didn't understand what you want

Comment: Thank you! Think of a traffic matrix. It has a source where the traffic is coming from and a destination where it goes.There is a value for each traffic that goes from a source to destination. 
Now I'm given a list of traffic values with sources and destinations. I want to automatically input these details to a matrix where sources are shown from the rows and destinations are from columns.
Later I want to refer to the source, destination pair corresponding to 1 traffic value. Hence I want to create another matrix with the same dimension which is filled with source-destination pairs

Comment: Currently your code gives as output: `array([[  0.,  22.,  34.],
       [ 43.,   0.,  56.],
       [ 37.,  45.,   0.]])` but you want that the output became the same as in your question, that's it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding use below application code(tested in python 3.6.2):

```
import numpy as np
matrixlist=[]
tuple1=()
list1=[]
list1=tuple(tuple1)
rows= 3
cols=3

a = np.zeros((rows*cols))
for i in range(rows):
    list1=[]
    list1.append(i)
    t1=tuple(list1)
    for j in range(cols):
        list1=list(t1)
        list1.append(j)
        t2=tuple(list1)
        matrixlist.append(t2)
        list1.remove(list1[0])
data=[]
data= matrixlist
i=0
m=[data[i:i+cols] for i in range(0, len(data), cols)]
print(m)
```

**OutPUT:**

```
[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)], [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)], [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]]
```

Hope this will full fill your requirement!

Comment: Yes, it is perfect.

Comment: @ShenuAmaya You seen my answer? It is a way much more simple and gives almost the same result. The exception is that the internal elements are not tuple. Or that was a requirement too?

Comment: @H. Tacon: yes you are right. As per my understanding it is required internal element as tuple .

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, you need to add the following code after extracting the `rows` and `cols`:

```
a = np.array([[(i, j) for j in range(max(cols)+1)] for i in range(max(rows)+1)])
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[[[0 0] [0 1] [0 2]]  [[1 0] [1 1] [1 2]]  [[2 0] [2 1] [2 2]]]
```

extracts how many columns and rows you have in your matrix, add 1 (since `range` by default is open in the upper bound of the interval) and then populate it with the values of currents row and column. If you know beforehand the size o matrix you can replace the values inside range like this:

```
a = np.array([[(i, j) for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)])
```

Otherwise you can leave as above and base it on your source/destination list.